# Jquery get input value via TD closest input

Tags: jquery

i've looked at similar examples at stackoverflow and i think i got the code correctly but it doesn't work.

1. my TD's are generated by grid object on a fly
2. i'm trying to get (and eventually change) value of the fist empty input that is positioned inside `<td col="isrc">`:

   ```
   $("#get_isrc").click(function(){
       $.ajax({
           url: 'isrc.php',
           success: function(data){
               $("#new_isrc").val(data);
               $("#get_isrc").val('Apply');
               $("#get_isrc").addClass('apply');
           }               
       }).error(function(){
           alert('Error');
       });
   });

   $(".apply").click(function(){
       var s = $("td[col=ISRC] input").val();
       alert(s);
   });
   ```

html - static:

```
<h3>Generate next ISRC</h3>
    <input id="new_isrc" type="text" />
    <input id="get_isrc" type="button" value="Get next ISRC" />
```

html generated by jquery:

```
<tr id="3"><td col="ISRC" style="width: 101px; " class="editableCell"><input class="editableInput " type="text"></td></tr>
<tr id="1"><td col="ISRC" style="width: 101px; " class="editableCell"><input class="editableInput " type="text"></td></tr>
<tr id="2"><td col="ISRC" style="width: 101px; " class="editableCell"><input class="editableInput " type="text"></td></tr>
```

tr's 1 and 2 have ISRC values from database

tr 3 - is newly added and i want generated isrc applied to it, but at the moment my code just need to alert me of a new value - it does work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried using live instead as its generated after document.ready

```
$(".apply").live("click", function(){
    var s = $("td[col=ISRC] input").val();
    alert(s);
   //$(s).focus();
});
```

Comment: yes. this did work. funny enough i used live() a bit above this code for the same reason! i need weekend...... thank you

Comment: i'm having difficulties, changing value.. should i use another live() inside live()? - $(".apply").live("click", function(){
   if ( !$("td[col=ISRC] input").val() ){
    this.val($("#new_isrc").val());
   }
  });

Comment: if (s === "") { $(this).val(($("#new_isrc").val()));} im assuming you want to do, if s.value is blank then set it to the value of #new_isrc ??

Comment: hi Owen, yes, that's exactly what i want! but unfortunately your code didn't work either =(

Comment: or can i be because i need to check each() "td[col=ISRC] input" (as i have about 10 per page and the top one 'maybe' blank, but td[col=ISRC] isn't the first td you match on the page.. although it's not apparent from the example...

Comment: sorry im completely confused on what your trying to do now, post another question with the new issue and i'll help with that!